# Maximum size for a byte[] in a .Net DataSet/DataTable

Tags: ado.net, dataset, limits

Is there any maximum size for a cell of data in a DataTable (like a byte[]), or can you grow it until the system runs out of memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no hardcoded limit.

If you're storing it as a byte[], you'll have a 2GB limit (even on 64bit systems), since you cannot make an array with more than Integer.MaxValue elements, which, with byte per element, would be 2GB.